# Why can't I launch a WPF app written in F#?

Tags: wpf, f#

**I receive the following warning when attempting to build a WPF app written in F#:**

> Main module of program is empty: nothing will happen when it is run

**As a result, I am unable to launch the application.**

I have verified that all **AssemblyInfo.fs** files has a "do()" at the end.
I have played around with the order of files as well.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

I Added a file to the end of my project.

The file has the following code:

```
module Bootstrap

open System.Windows

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Run() |> ignore;
    // Return 0. This indicates success.
    0
```

When I attempt to run the file though, I hit a null reference exception on Application.Current.

My solution looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you have an entry point? Can you show its code?

Comment: Try creating an entry point and calling Application.Run() from there. E.g. `[<EntryPoint>] let main args = Application.Run(); 0`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what DPI are you running VS at? That looks crazy big.

Comment: That's just the way the image is presented. It's not that large on my VS app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a minimal working example, using `FSharp.ViewModule.Core` and `FsXaml.Wpf` packages:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ViewModel;assembly=fsxamltest">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
</Window>
```

ViewModel.fs:

```
namespace ViewModel
open FSharp.ViewModule
type MainViewModel() as me = inherit ViewModelBase()
```

App.fs:

```
open System
type App = FsXaml.XAML<"App.xaml">
[<STAThread;EntryPoint>]
let main _ = App().Root.Run()
```

App.xaml:

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"/>
```

If that doesn't work, please show us the full code or create [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In addition, I had to set MainWindow.xaml and App.xaml build action to "Resource".